# How to add new value user field in sharepoint list?

Tags: lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

I have people look up field in my list ..lets say "Checker" , its single selection user field but when i try to add user data to "Checker" field through rest api its not getting posted ...

```
$scope.formData.Checker.Title=$("#checker").val();
```

This is how i am storing data but when I hit save and check the list its storing the data to "Title" field but not "Checker" field. btw "Title" is the another field in my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Single user field value**

The example demonstrates how to create a task item and specify a single-valued `AssignedTo` field

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    'AssignedToId' : 10
};
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',taskProperties)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

You have to pass ID instead of value as text (name).

Comment: Can you please accept the answer & make it upvote so others can get benefit from it by identifying that it is working solution?

Comment: how about multiple values ?? i applied the same formula but it dint work @hardik